# Solving linear system using inverse or triangular factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

There are at least two general ways to solve linear equations $Ax=b$.

- First approach: compute $A^{-1}$ using Gauss-Jordan method, then $x=A^{-1}b$.
- Second approach: compute the triangular factorization $A=LU$, then solve $Lc=b$ and $Ux=c$ respectively.

Which is more preferred and why?

Comment: I would say it is **not** triangular factorization. The quickest method to invert a matrix is, I believe, using Gauss-Jordan method and that produces the triangular factorization along the way. Since after inverting all it takes is multiplying, but with triangular factorization you still have a system to solve, I would say it is preferred to invert the matrix.

Comment: In a strictly computational approach, the most efficient between the two is the triangular factorization, especially if the matrix is very big in dimensions; the two linear systems to solve are very simple. There is a third approach though: approximate solutions, like the Classic/Conjugate Gradient method for example. It depends on what one needs. In general though, just for solving some linear system you don't need to invert the matrix

Comment: @RSerrao: strange comment, given that Gauss-Jordan is slightly more costly than pure Gauss, itself equivalent to LU factorization.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how to compute $A^{-1}$ in the first option, so the comparison isn't really possible.

A common way is by solving $AA'=I$, which gives $A'=A^{-1}$. This is certainly a very inefficient method, because it amounts to solving $n$ systems of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns, when you initially wanted to solve a single one.

If you need to solve a single system, $LU$ factorization is unnecessary, use pure Gaussian elimination (though the only difference lies in the storage of the coefficients).

The most important: use partial or total pivoting.